# Elements Relocate as Page Gets Wider

Tags: javascript, css, forms, material-ui

I am working on making more accessible web pages.  I am running into a problem where as I make my page wider the elements seem to relocate farther down the screen.  I believe this is because I am setting a upper margin based on % not fixed.  I am not totally sure why the height would be increasing as the screen is made wider.  Are height and width set in a fixed ratio when flexGrow is used?

I am using material-ui with these style overrides:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root : {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
},
  form: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    width: '75%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginTop: '40%',
    marginBottom: '50%',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 35,
    minHeight: 200,
  },

})
```

Here is the form element which I am working with:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.login}>
       <Typography component="h2" variant="headline">Login</Typography>
    </form>
</div>
```

I would expect the height of the form to stay fixed when the width is increasing but this is not the result I am seeing.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the running code?

Comment: https://beer-rating.herokuapp.com/#/home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `flex-grow` is a property you would set on a flex child. It does nothing when added to the flex parent `.jss2`. You can actually just remove it.

For `.jss3` to remain vertically centered, remove the following:

- `margin-top: 40%;`
- `margin-bottom: 50%;`

And add the following to `.jss2`: `align-items: center;`

Without being able to test the styles ported to `JavaScript`, I'm somewhat confident this will work:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root : {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
  form: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    width: '75%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 35,
    minHeight: 200,
  }
})
```